# Generic Oracle Lookup Validation Function

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracleforms

I have several Tables that contains just id and description in that particular schema, i wonder if it is possible to write one generic function which will read something like:

```
create or replace FUNCTION tab_lookup (key_field char,key_value char,from_table char,return_field char) RETURN char IS
a varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

select &return_field into a
from &from_table  
where &key_field=key_value;
return(a);
exception 
    when others
    then 
    return('*ERR*');
END;
```

i want to use it at inside package application which only 50 users will be using.

Comment: You can always set up foreign key constraints.

Comment: foreign keys are already there .. i am just trying to speed up front-end development.

Comment: You do know that this will save you exactly 1 character per invocation? `a := tab_lookup('keyfield', 'keyvalue', 'mytable', 'returnfield');` vs `select returnfield into a from mytable where keyfield = 'keyvalue';`

Comment: sorry that couldnot get your point.  
"You do know that this will save you exactly 1 character per invocation?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your version, by changing it using `Dynamic SQL` and changed the Input parameters' Datatype as `VARCHAR2`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tab_lookup (key_field VARCHAR2,
                                       key_value VARCHAR2,
                                       from_table VARCHAR2,
                                       return_field VARCHAR2,
                                       return_type VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
result_a varchar2(1000);
query_string VARCHAR2(4000);
/*version 0.1*/
BEGIN

  query_string := 'SELECT '||return_field|| 
                  'FROM '||from_table||  
                  'WHERE '||key_field || ' = :key_value ';

  IF(return_type = 'SQL') THEN
     result_a := query_string;
  ELSE

       //this line will not work in forms 6i remove the using key_value word
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_string USING key_value  into result_a;
  END IF;

  RETURN (result_a);
EXCEPTION 

 // add DBMS_ASSERT Exceptions
WHEN 
    NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
       RETURN(NULL);
WHEN
    TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
       RETURN('**ERR_DUPLICATE**');
WHEN OTHERS
THEN 
        RETURN('*ERR_'||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: Why would there be single quotes to escape? The values being concatenated can't contain them, and the bind variable doesn't need escaping. It might be worth checking the passed values are at least valid identifiers, with [`DBMS_ASSERT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_assert.htm), before concatenating to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: It would be very nice of if you could demonstrate the DBMS_ASSERT in context